# CodeLens only showing references?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, codelens

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RTM and only seeing "references" from Code Lens. We are using TFS for source control. I expect to see related commits from TFS. [Based on this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx), I have everything enabled in options:

[image]

Here is what I see in VS:

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my VS setup?

Comment: What version of TFS are you connected to? Only TFS 2013 and up are able to generate the background data required for these to work. See also: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/12/codelens-features-and-visual-studio.html

Comment: It's also possible that your server admin had disabled indexing, or that the indecing for your project hasn't completed yet. See also: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/05/controlling-whether-codelens-runs.html

Comment: @jessehouwing: Both of your comments are valid points. I will need to find out. Meanwhile feel free to post as an answer to be accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TFVC lenses that are part of CodeLens only work when connected to a version of Team Foundation Server that is running the background job that generates the historical data. This means that you need to be running at least TFS 2013 or 2015 in order for this feature to work. Some features require a [specific version of Visual Studio](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/12/codelens-features-and-visual-studio.html).

It is also possible that your [server admin has disabled indexing on the server](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/05/controlling-whether-codelens-runs.html), one can do that using the `tfsconfig codeindex` command on the application tier.

Comment: Our problem was TFS 2010, hopefully we will upgrade soon. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an article or documentation (published by Microsoft/Visual Studio Team) where I can find the detailed requirements for that feature?

Comment: @MarcusDock VS2015: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx and VS2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218(v=vs.120).aspx requirements are mentioned per feature.