# "Codelens server returned forbidden (403) for C:\....aspx.cs" on VS2017 Pro opening solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, visual-studio-2017, codelens

I have Visual Studio 2017 Professional and all CodeLens options are turned on. When I open one of our solutions (linked to TFS 2010 source control) I get the above error (with the filename fully specified) in the "Source Control - Team Foundation" output pane. I've tried explicitly running VS2017 as Administrator with no change.

Is this something to be concerned about? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MSDN [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx#Find%20your%20code%27s%20history%20and%20linked%20items), it says that,

> Team Foundation Server 2013 or later, Visual Studio Team Services, or Git

You need  to use TFS 2013 and upper version. TFS 2010 is not supported. It is also referred in the case: [CodeLens only showing references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570140/codelens-only-showing-references)

You could upgrade to TFS 2013 or later version to make it works.