# Method reference not showing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my Visual Studio 2022, method references are not showing. I checked the options menu and I see this:

"Show C# and visual basic references" is greyed out.

[image: Current Options Menu]

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "Show C# and visual basic references" is grayed out. This is because this is a consideration that exists from the beginning of the design of Visual Studio. At least one item is visible for each CodeLens entry. Otherwise, the user may end up seeing a blank space where the CodeLens should be displayed.

For details, please refer to: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36378

That is to say, as long as you select CodeLens, "Show C# and visual basic references" is turned on by default.

If you want to fix method references not showing, please refer to: [CodeLens not showing references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823805/codelens-not-showing-references)

If none of these work, you can try to use the Visual Studio Installer to repair or update Visual Studio.

Update:

[image]

Repair:

[image]